# htaccess protect all subfolders & files

Tags: .htaccess

I have this situation:

```
/storage
  index.php
  other scripts.php
  /files  
    -files and folders-
```

I want to deny all the HTTP requests to all files and subfolders of `/files` but in the same time allowing to access `/storage` and run those PHP scripts. I tried some rules but they either protect only the listing of files or don't allow access to all the `/storage` folder.

The `.htaccess` must be outside `/files` (because this folder is accessed by PHP `readfile` and `.htaccess` could be accessible).

Answer (score 7):

In your root .htaccess file i.e. under `/storage` directory put this line:

```
RewriteRule ^files/ - [R=404,L,NC]
```

This will throw `404` to all the HTTP requests for anything under `files/` sub directory while your `.php` files will be able to include files under `files/` sub directory.

Comment: it doesn't work I can still access the files, for example /files/image.jpg is visible

Comment: Is your .htaccess being read? Before posting I've tested this above rule on my Linux, Mac and XAMPP installations and it has worked everywhere.

Comment: @anubhava I have a htaccess problem can you answer my question please, looks like you are the best on regex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017924/htaccess-code-not-working-when-i-move-my-files-in-subfolder

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this, in the parent directory (you may want to use the full path)

```
<Directory ./Files>
  ORDER DENY, ALLOW
  DENY FROM ALL
</DIRECTORY>
```

In general I'd recomend that you simply put your /files directory somewhere outside the document root for safety. That way if .htaccess accidentally gets turned off or broken you don't end up exposing the files.

Edit:

My apologies, The `<Directory>` directive is only valid in the server config (you'd need to put it in the httpd.conf file or equivalent), not in .htaccess. If you're sure of the types of files you're going to be putting in the directory you can use the `<Files>` directive with the various file types: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files this would however need to be put in the `Files` directory. (then possibly just exclude it from the PHP script, though many ignore hidden files already).