# How do I "hide" subfolders on my Site?

Tags: html, security

I wasn't sure what the best way to hone in on searching this, but I have a relatively simple question:

Say I have mysite.com
Then I have mysite.com/images

How do I protect that subfolder from being accessed by anyone?  I have multiple folders spread across the site like that.  I am a novice when it comes to this.  Do I place a file in each folder, popping up some sort of error?  Should I redirect or maybe have a screen that pops up a site map?

Comment: How to secure directories is something that should be handled by the OS and web server. It is **not** normally a programming issue.

Comment: This depends on what web server etc. you are using.

Answer (score 0):

What webserver do you use? When you use apache you can create `.htaccess` files in the folders you want to protect. E.g. you can allow access to the directory from the ip address 1.2.3.4, the others are blocked using this lines in your htaccess file:

```
order deny,allow    
allow from 1.2.3.4
deny from all
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.htaccess` to do that. Here is a link to a good way to do it: [htaccess protect all subfolders & files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246664/htaccess-protect-all-subfolders-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the folder to have a `.` in front of it. In your case,

```
.images
```

Simply navigate through whatever file system you use, find the folder and rename it to put a `.` in front of it.

This way, nobody will be able to access it from the browser/another server (basically it is inaccessible to everyone except you and your server scripts). Though, if you have images that are being shown in a web page you will not be able to use this method.